# Microsoft OWIN Test Server setting cookies

Tags: c#, owin, dotnet-httpclient

I have an Owin Test Server:

```
using (var testServer = TestServer.Create<TestPipelineConfiguration>())
using (var client = new HttpClient(testServer.Handler))
{
    client
        .DefaultRequestHeaders
        .Add("Cookie", $"{AspNetCookies}=HeyThere;");

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://testserver/");

    var message = client
                    .PostAsync("print", new StringContent(
                                                jsonProvider.SerialiseObject(new
                                                {
                                                    Url = "https://some/url"
                                                }),
                                                Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
                    .Result;

    //var message = client.GetAsync("test").Result;

    message
        .StatusCode
        .ShouldBeEquivalentTo(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

I want to set other properties on that cookie, like `HttpOnly`, `Secure` and `Domain`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Cookie is a header with list of key-value items. In your code it will look like this:

```
.Add("Cookie", "cookie1=value1;cookie2=value2")
```

Comment: how does that answer the question: `I want to set other properties on that cookie, like HttpOnly, Secure and Domain`

Answer (score 1):

Properties are part of the cookie value, semicolon separated, e.g.
"Cookie=cookievalue; path=/; HttpOnly"

Comment: I wish I could test this right away to confirm, but I have since moved on the project that contained this - however I will try to as soon as I can

Comment: Funny thing - I've just started my own project which I expect can test this out. So will give it a go at some point